How to migrate from Paid app to In App Purchase
I have one paid app on Play Store. Now I want to use In App Purchase model for additional paid features. But now I want to introduce free sample app. Users can buy full app version, additional app features through In App Purchase. Currently checking Play license check api to verify paid app users.
I have few questions related to this :-

How to identify paid app users and new sample users when app is made free ?
Is it possible to migrate old paid app users to In App purchase model without any backend server ?

Note:- My app doesn't have any registration feature.
I read In App Billing and Play License check api docs but it doesn't mention anything related to Paid app to In app purchase migration.

Did you find a solution for this?
